# Birthdays without years in Google Contacts (2018 version) are out by 1 day

Tags: google-contacts

When *viewing* a Contact in the new (2018) Google Contacts in a browser on desktop, the birth date is out by 1 day (1 day early) when the birth date is entered without a year, eg. "13 July" shows as "12 July" when *viewing* the contact. When a year is entered then the date is *viewed* correctly. eg. "13 July 1980" shows as "13 July 1980".

However, editing the contact shows the correct date. But if I change/edit the date and "save", it then shows the date-less-1-day again when viewing the contact! eg. If I enter "1 July" when editing the contact, hit "save", the date appears as "30 June" when *viewing* the contact.

However, the correct date does appear in "other" places. For example:

- The Google "Birthdays" Calendar reports the correct date (which is derived from the Google Contacts).
- Reverting to the "old" Gmail Contacts shows the correct date when *viewed*.
- The Android Contacts app shows the correct date.

This seems like a bug to me, but I can't find any other reports of similar problems?

Comment: I'm not seeing this behavior. What timezone are you in?

Comment: @ale Timezone BST (UTC+1)

Comment: That might be related. I'm in UTC-4. It sounds like a bug to me. I suggest using the "Send Feedback" tool at the bottom of the left nav bar to report it.

Comment: Related from [android.se] : [Google Calendar app entries on Android Device inconsistent with web browser entries](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/103163/71386) (from 2015, no answer at this time)

Answer (score 2):

Same problem here for (at least) one contact. When viewing the birth date it is one day earlier than when editing. Locale Netherlands. Date specified as 12 juni 1960 is viewed as 11 juni 1960 and also shown in google calendar on june 11th.

However I found out that on my samsung android 6 tablet an (birthday) event existed for this contact on the wrong date. After correcting this event the problem in Google Contacts (desktop browser) was solved. I am using the Samsung contacts app on the tablet, so maybe something goes wrong during sync.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Google Calendar. And a really annoying one. It happened multiple times to me that I congratulated too early. The last time just now.

I can not recreate the bug however. For new contacts it seems to be fixed.
So this maybe only relates to old/synced contacts/entries.

I didn't find the information anymore. If I remember correctly it was also problematic for users with birth years before a certain year. Maybe 1900.